# How to extend my endpoint with /download/?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

My code looks like this:

```
# models.py
class Recording(models.Model):
    title = . . . 
    duration = . . .

# views.py
class RecordingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RecordingSerializer
    . . . 

# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'recordings', RecordingViewSet, base_name='recordings')
```

How can I extend my endpoint to create a /recordings/X/ endpoint? (in my case X = download)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your current `urls.py` to create an endpoint with a `ViewSet` that deals with downloading.

You can create this endpoint by adding:

```
router.register(r'recordings/download', RecordingViewSet, base_name='recordings/download')
```

When going to `/recordings/download/` whatever functionality you have in `RecordingViewSet` will run.

You can also keep `/recordings` and assign a different `ViewSet` to that endpoint like this:

```
router.register(r'recordings', SomeViewSet, base_name='recordings')
```

[DRF-Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) about how routers in django-rest-framework work.

Comment: Can I keep both of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django Rest Framework version 3.8+, you can also use `@action` decorator for specific endpoints and actions below viewset. For example;

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response


# views.py
class RecordingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RecordingSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=["GET"])
    def download(self, request):
        # your logic here
        context = {'message': 'hi!'}
        return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and you will be able to access this endpoint as `/recordings/download/`.

See other usage examples and explanations from [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).